# Linux watchdog and timing interval

Tags: linux, sles, threads, watchdog

How does the `/dev/watchdog` timer exactly work? I found a description [here](http://kernel.org/doc/Documentation/watchdog/watchdog-api.txt) and it says that once I open the file from an application I need to 
update it every 10 seconds. I was wondering is this a hard limit? For example what if I update it in 11 seconds for instance?
Could someone explain the behavior to me please?
Because there are no "hard limits" in the thread scheduling so that I am certain that the file is updated in exactly 10 sec. **stricty** unless I use e.g. a spin loop instead of a `sleep`

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: I don't know how watchdog exactly works. But kernel features are usually well documented. For example in case of the watchdog there is a subdirectory called '/Documentation/watchdog' in the kernel source. There you should find a nice description

Comment: @mauro.stettler:Where is the kernel source?For example I have a sles installed.Is it in the file system this documentation?

Comment: if you installed the kernel-source rpm, then it is usually in /usr/src/linux. otherwise you can get it from http://www.kernel.org/